# Swift function not being called?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Alright, so i am making a video only app with AVKit and MobileCoreServices. The video part works perfect except for when I click "Use Video", it doesn't save it like it's supposed to. Here are all my functions being called upon:

**This function isn't being called correctly for some reason but i am receiving no errors or console errors/warnings**
[image]

**Here is my extension where i am calling the video function in the UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum.**
[image]

**Here is the button action, where when it is pressed, i am calling the startCameraFromViewController function.**
[image]

**And finally here is the startCameraFromViewController function.**
[image]

Comment: Have you verified that control goes into your `if UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(path)` block?

Comment: Also, what's the full text of that warning on your imagePickerController delegate method?

Comment: Please do not post your code as images. Please copy and paste the actual code.

Comment: Sorry @rmaddy I figured it would be best that way because the warnings are showed. Ill post actual code from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that your `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` method signature doesn't quite match.  (Probably the example you used was from Swift 2 and has changed for Swift 3).  The proper signature is:

```
optional func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, 
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])
```

Note the underscore before the first argument.